# run: open server: open service: listen tcp :8086: bind: address already in use on starting influxdb

Tags: macos, influxdb

I am setting up influx DB (InfluxDB shell version: v1.7.6).I have made changes in configuration file.But when I start service using command-

```
It gives me error that bind port 8086 is already in use & graphite service does not start


# Change this option to true to disable reporting.
 reporting-disabled = false
 hostname=""
 join=""


# Bind address to use for the RPC service for backup and restore.
  bind-address = ":8088"

###
### [meta]
###
### Controls the parameters for the Raft consensus group that stores metadata
### about the InfluxDB cluster.
###
```

This is configuration for meta tag
    [meta]

```
  dir = "/usr/local/var/influxdb/meta"

  # Automatically create a default retention policy when creating a database.
    retention-autocreate = true

  # If log messages are printed for the meta service
    logging-enabled = true

[[graphite]]
  # Determines whether the graphite endpoint is enabled.
   enabled = true
   database = "jmeter"
   retention-policy = ""
   bind-address = ":2003"
   protocol = "tcp"
   consistency-level = "one

Above is the my influxdb properties.I have restarted service after configuration changes.

I am setting up influx DB (InfluxDB shell version: v1.7.6).I have made changes in configuration file.But when I start service using command-

It gives me error that bind port 8086 is already in use & graphite service does not start


# Change this option to true to disable reporting.
 reporting-disabled = false
 hostname=""
 join=""


# Bind address to use for the RPC service for backup and restore.
  bind-address = ":8088"

###
### [meta]
###
### Controls the parameters for the Raft consensus group that stores metadata
### about the InfluxDB cluster.
###

[meta]
  # Where the metadata/raft database is stored
  dir = "/usr/local/var/influxdb/meta"

  # Automatically create a default retention policy when creating a database.
    retention-autocreate = true

  # If log messages are printed for the meta service
    logging-enabled = true

[[graphite]]
  # Determines whether the graphite endpoint is enabled.
   enabled = true
   database = "jmeter"
   retention-policy = ""
   bind-address = ":2003"
   protocol = "tcp"
   consistency-level = "one

Above is the my influxdb properties.I have restarted service after configuration changes.
```

Code is not needed for this

Answer (score 1):

It is because another process is using the port 8086. You can find the process using following commands:

```
netstat -a | grep 8086
```

If you have root permission:

```
lsof -i:8086
```

Identify the other process id and kill it using

```
kill -9 <process id>
```

Or configure influx using another port.

Answer (score 0):

restarting influxdb helped me

```sh
sudo systemctl restart influxd.service
sudo systemctl restart influxdb.service
```