# InfluxDB not starting: 8086 bind address already in use

Tags: database, influxdb

I have an InfluxDB Version 1.8.9, but I can't start it.
In this example I'm logged in as a root.

```
netstat -lptn
```

gives me a range of services, none of them seem to listen to 8086. (there are other services running like grafana or MySQL, which seem to work fine)

To further confirm nothing is on 8086,I listened to that related Issue [run: open server: open service: listen tcp :8086: bind: address already in use on starting influxdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56459872/run-open-server-open-service-listen-tcp-8086-bind-address-already-in-use-o)
and run

```
netstat -a | grep 8086
```

which results in no results.

My config file on /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf looks like this:

```
reporting-disabled = false
bind-address = "127.0.0.1:8086"

[meta]
  #dir = "/root/.influxdb/meta"
  dir = "/var/lib/influxdb/meta"
  retention-autocreate = true
  logging-enabled = true

[data]
  dir = "/var/lib/influxdb/data"
  index-version = "inmem"
  wal-dir = "/var/lib/influxdb/wal"
  wal-fsync-delay = "0s"
  validate-keys = false
  strict-error-handling = false
  query-log-enabled = true
  cache-max-memory-size = 1073741824
  cache-snapshot-memory-size = 26214400
  cache-snapshot-write-cold-duration = "10m0s"
  compact-full-write-cold-duration = "4h0m0s"
  compact-throughput = 50331648
  compact-throughput-burst = 50331648
  max-series-per-database = 1000000
  max-values-per-tag = 100000
  max-concurrent-compactions = 0
  max-index-log-file-size = 1048576
  series-id-set-cache-size = 100
  series-file-max-concurrent-snapshot-compactions = 0
  trace-logging-enabled = false
  tsm-use-madv-willneed = false
  ...
  [http]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = ":8086"
  auth-enabled = false
  log-enabled = true
  suppress-write-log = false
  write-tracing = false
  flux-enabled = false
  flux-log-enabled = false
  pprof-enabled = true
  pprof-auth-enabled = false
  debug-pprof-enabled = false
  ping-auth-enabled = false
  prom-read-auth-enabled = false
  https-enabled = false
  https-certificate = "/etc/ssl/influxdb.pem"
  https-private-key = ""
  max-row-limit = 0
  max-connection-limit = 0
  shared-secret = ""
  realm = "InfluxDB"
  unix-socket-enabled = false
  unix-socket-permissions = "0777"
  bind-socket = "/var/run/influxdb.sock"
  max-body-size = 25000000
  access-log-path = ""
  max-concurrent-write-limit = 0
  max-enqueued-write-limit = 0
  enqueued-write-timeout = 30000000000
  ...
```

So i tried to start my database:

```
service influxdb start
```

Which gives me

> ob for influxdb.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See
> "systemctl status influxdb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

result of **systemctl status influxdb.service**

```
● influxdb.service - InfluxDB is an open-source, distributed, time series database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/influxdb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Tue 2021-09-21 18:37:12 CEST; 1min 7s ago
     Docs: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/
 Main PID: 32016 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE); Control PID: 5874 (influxd-systemd)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/influxdb.service
           ├─5874 /bin/bash -e /usr/lib/influxdb/scripts/influxd-systemd-start.sh
           └─5965 sleep 10

Sep 21 18:37:23 s22227708 influxd-systemd-start.sh[5874]: ts=2021-09-21T16:37:23.515897Z lvl=info msg="Registered diagnostics client" log_id=0WjJLI7l000 service=monitor name=runtime
Sep 21 18:37:23 s22227708 influxd-systemd-start.sh[5874]: ts=2021-09-21T16:37:23.515907Z lvl=info msg="Registered diagnostics client" log_id=0WjJLI7l000 service=monitor name=network
Sep 21 18:37:23 s22227708 influxd-systemd-start.sh[5874]: ts=2021-09-21T16:37:23.515923Z lvl=info msg="Registered diagnostics client" log_id=0WjJLI7l000 service=monitor name=system
Sep 21 18:37:23 s22227708 influxd-systemd-start.sh[5874]: ts=2021-09-21T16:37:23.515977Z lvl=info msg="Starting precreation service" log_id=0WjJLI7l000 service=shard-precreation check_interval=10m advanc
Sep 21 18:37:23 s22227708 influxd-systemd-start.sh[5874]: ts=2021-09-21T16:37:23.515995Z lvl=info msg="Starting snapshot service" log_id=0WjJLI7l000 service=snapshot
Sep 21 18:37:23 s22227708 influxd-systemd-start.sh[5874]: ts=2021-09-21T16:37:23.516015Z lvl=info msg="Starting continuous query service" log_id=0WjJLI7l000 service=continuous_querier
Sep 21 18:37:23 s22227708 influxd-systemd-start.sh[5874]: ts=2021-09-21T16:37:23.516011Z lvl=info msg="Storing statistics" log_id=0WjJLI7l000 service=monitor db_instance=_internal db_rp=monitor interval=
Sep 21 18:37:23 s22227708 influxd-systemd-start.sh[5874]: ts=2021-09-21T16:37:23.516037Z lvl=info msg="Starting HTTP service" log_id=0WjJLI7l000 service=httpd authentication=false
Sep 21 18:37:23 s22227708 influxd-systemd-start.sh[5874]: ts=2021-09-21T16:37:23.516052Z lvl=info msg="opened HTTP access log" log_id=0WjJLI7l000 service=httpd path=stderr
Sep 21 18:37:23 s22227708 influxd-systemd-start.sh[5874]: run: open server: open service: listen tcp :8086: bind: address already in use
```

I can't really understand where I did something wrong, since I configured :8086 in the config file. Can you help me?

Comment: Hi @SebastianKollmar, I couldn't help but notice what looks like a typo in your config file. You wrote `http-bind-address: ":8086"` but looking at the doc it seems to be `http-bind-address: ":8086"`. Notice the key are different ? I am not sure it will fix your issue tho https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/config-options/#http-bind-address

Comment: Do you have the same issue when changing to other ports ? Maybe before doing any modification as suggested above. Try changing ports. Does the issue persist when you do so ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed it to http-bind-address from just bind-address, but as you expected, no different result.

Comment: How about changing port ? Does it fail too ?

Comment: I tried it and it worked! I changed to 8087 and it worked. But more interestingly, I changed it back to 8086 and this worked to. Now everything seems fine. No idea what was the problem, I just changed the port in config file to the exact same thing. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I did a summary of our tests, please feel free to edit it if it lacks any details.

Comment: Hey Sebastian, if you could find the time to review my answer and accept it ot would be lovely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a typo in the configuration file.
As stated in [the documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/config-options/#http-bind-address), the configuration file should hold `http-bind-address` instead of `bind-address`. As well as a locked port by the first configuration.

The first few lines of the file `/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf` should look like so:

```
reporting-disabled = false
http-bind-address = "127.0.0.1:8086"
```

A suggested approach would be to:

1. `bind-address` to `http-bind-address`
2. Changing the port from default `8086` to a known free port
3. (Optional) Back to the default port.

Answer (score 0):

From your config:

```
  reporting-disabled = false
  bind-address = "127.0.0.1:8086"
  ...
  [http]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = ":8086"
```

Both your 'native' service and the 'http' service are configured to use the same port 8086.  This cannot work and you probably want to change the 'native' port back to its default of 8088.